# Microsoft Access Report

Tags: report

I have 2 tables: `Customer` and `Sales`. The customer table has:

```
Customer Number
Customer Name
Customer Location
```

The sales table has:

```
Customer Number
Sales Date
Sales Amount
```

I created the relationship between the tables based on customer number.  I can do a query that links up the data from each table.

What I have not been able to do is to summarize my Access report.

I only want `Customer Number`, `Customer Name` and `Customer Location` to show up once and I want each `Sales Date` and `Sales Amount` to show up associated with that customer.

Right now, when I do my report, `Customer Number`, `Customer Name` and `Customer Location` gets repeated for each sale.

For instance, if Customer A has 3 sales, Customer A shows up 3 times.  I want Customer A to show up once, with the 3 sales listed individually underneath Customer A.

I can summarize it by `Customer Number` (using a group, I think), but `Customer Name` and `Customer Location` still show up multiple times.

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all fields that you want to show up once in the group header.